# string and powershell extract user name from the array

Tags: string, powershell

I have this code, when i excute this powershell code:

```
Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
```

I will get:

```
UserName               
--------               
DESKTOP-JBJN9QA\joli
```

How can i extract only the name joli 
thank you

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Expandproperty UserName` doesn't work for me - so if you don't want

```
Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object PrimaryOwnerName
```

Try

```
(Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName.split('\')[1]
```